# Writing HTML with JavaScript using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

So I've got this PHP that's writing some JavaScript that looks something like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">

var videoArr=["'.implode('", "', $videos).'"];
var titleArr=["'.implode('", "', $titles).'"];
var explanationArr=["'.implode('", "', $explanations).'"];
var i = 0;

function appendVideo(i) {

var url ="http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoArr[i] + "?rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0";

$("#stage").append("<div class=\"video\">");
$("#stage").append(titleArr[i] + "<br />");
$("#stage").append("<iframe width=\"400\" height=\"225\" src=\"" + url + "\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>");
$("#stage").append("<br /><img src=\"images/btn_play.png\" onclick=\"play(\'" + videoArr[i] + "\')\" />");
$("#stage").append("<img src=\"images/btn_show.png\" onclick=\"show(\'" + videoArr[i] + "\')\" /><br />");
$("#stage").append("</div>");
}

</script>';
```

But after reading this: http://littleurl.info/wdl I've learned that I have to do this all in one append for my DIV tags to appear correctly. However I'm finding it impossible to get my syntax correct because I'm doing this all through PHP. Can anyone help me debug the code below? Please remember it's all contained in an echo with single inverted commas.

```
$("#stage").append("<div class=\"video\">"+ titleArr[i] + "<br />
<iframe width=\"400\" height=\"225\" src=\"" + url + "\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />
<img src=\"images/btn_play.png\" onclick=\"play(\'" + videoArr[i] + "\')\" />
<img src=\"images/btn_show.png\" onclick=\"show(\'" + videoArr[i] + "\')\" /><br />
</div>");
```

Comment: Single-quotes are valid for HTML attributes. That will at least get rid of some of the horrible escaping. You might also want to look into using a JS templating language to make this easier.

Comment: You have PHP that writes JavaScript that writes HTML... there must be a better way.

Comment: You're making this harder on yourself by mixing everything up in PHP. Either break out of the PHP block and embed the php itself, like `<?php echo $var; ?>` or use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax. Also see [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) if you need to assign the output to a variable.

Comment: Look at your code highlighting on the question above; something is not right.

Comment: @sachleen It's a necessary evil I'm afraid.

Comment: You really are doing this the hardest possible way? Start your php right before the variables, echo the variables and close the php tag, and write your JS directly in the file. Then just restart a php tag later in the document if needed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving your HTML/Javascript in variables in PHP using [heredoc syntax](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html), so you don't need to escape everything:

```
<?php

$javascript_part_1 = <<<END_SCRIPT

    <script>
    ...

END_SCRIPT;

$javascript_part_2 = <<<END_SCRIPT

    ...

END_SCRIPT;

$javascript_part_3 = <<<END_SCRIPT

    ...
    </script>

END_SCRIPT;

?>
```

Then, simply use `echo` with PHP's string concatenation:

```
echo $javascript_part_1 . $videos . $javascript_part_2 . $titles . $javascript_part_3;
```

Comment: Found out where the syntax problem was. But yeah, this would be a good way to avoid confusion.

Comment: Just a little correction to your pseudo code: the closing of heredoc sections allows no characters on the left (incl. spaces, tabs etc.)

Comment: @inhan Good point. I only put the whitespace for readability.